# Ant exec behaves differently to command line with S3Sync

Tags: ant, amazon-s3

I'd like to create some ant targets to upload and download various file to Amazon S3. I've been using [S3Sync](http://sprightlysoft.com/S3Sync/) successfully from the command line and so I thought I'd just wrap this in an Ant exec

```
<exec executable="tools/s3sync/S3Sync.exe" failonerror="true" />
```

All of the config is in the config file S3Sync uses. I'll want to add some args and wrap in in a macrodef at some point, but I'm keeping it simple for this example.

Unfortunately, the exe doesn't appear to like running from Ant.

```
 [exec]
 [exec] Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
 [exec]
 [exec]    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 [exec]    at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
 [exec]    at System.Console.get_WindowWidth()
 [exec]    at S3Sync.Program.ClearProgressLines()
 [exec]    at S3Sync.Program.WriteConsoleLineClear(String InputLine)
 [exec]    at S3Sync.Program.WriteToLog(String LogLine, Int32 LogLineLevel)
 [exec]    at S3Sync.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I've tried setting dir, spawn, vmlauncher and other exec attributes, but to no avail.

Any thoughts on things I could try next?

Ant 1.8.4, Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like S3Sync is trying to clear the progress lines, and fails because it can't access the console. Makes sense, as you don't really have a console when running under Ant - at least not a console on which you can execute *all* I/O commands.

Did you try adding the `-ShowTransferProgress false` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my macrodefs for anyone else that would find them useful. My keys and other settings are set in my s3Sync.exe.config

```
<macrodef name="s3upload">
    <attribute name="bucket"/>
    <attribute name="logOnly" default="${s3upload.log.only}"/>
    <attribute name="localFolder"/>
    <sequential>
        <exec executable="${s3sync.exe}" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="-SyncDirection upload"/>
            <arg line="-LogOnlyMode @{logOnly}"/>
            <arg line="-BucketName @{bucket}"/>
            <arg line="-LocalFolderPath @{localFolder}"/>
            <arg line="-ShowTransferProgress false"/>
            <arg line="-UploadHeaders x-amz-acl:public-read"/>
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="s3download">
    <attribute name="bucket"/>
    <attribute name="logOnly" default="false"/>
    <attribute name="localFolder"/>
    <sequential>
        <exec executable="${s3sync.exe}" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="-SyncDirection download"/>
            <arg line="-LogOnlyMode @{logOnly}"/>
            <arg line="-BucketName @{bucket}"/>
            <arg line="-LocalFolderPath @{localFolder}"/>
            <arg line="-ShowTransferProgress false"/>
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

They get used like this

```
<s3download bucket="${s3.logs.bucket}" localFolder="${local.logs.path}" />
```